# How to add Time series queries with grafana and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, graph, panel, grafana

I'm new to grafana and playing around to see if it could fit my needs for a research lab.

I'm using grafana-server Version 4.5.2 (commit: ec2b0fe)

I tried to follow the grafana documentation about mysql datasources (sorry I'm not allowed to post more than two links, just try to search in your favorite search engine...)

I have succefully added a MySQL data source.

Here is my database :

```
mysql> DESC meteo;
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(100) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date_insert | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| temperature | float    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Following the documentation I've added a panel "Table" with the following query...

```
SELECT
  date_insert as 'Date',
  temperature as 'Temperature'
 FROM meteo
```

...and choosen "Format as Table"

The result is ok as you can see.

[Grafana Panel Format Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuyi8.png)

Now I would like to have a graph like this :

[Grafana Panel Format Time series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwkyJ.png)

How can I achieve this with my database ? I don't understand the doc which says :

> If you set Format as to Time series, for use in Graph panel for example,
>
> then there are some requirements for what your query returns.
>
> Must be a column named time_sec representing a unix epoch in seconds.
>
> Must be a column named value representing the time series value.
>
> Must be a column named metric representing the time series name.

How can I apply this with my database ? Is it just possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution, thanks to the Grafana team !

[daniellee's answer](https://community.grafana.com/t/how-to-add-time-series-queries-with-grafana-and-mysql/3170/2)

Comment: Answers should include more than a naked link